# Using Pinia store in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, storybook, pinia

I am creating a app which allows multiple themes. The theme id is stored in a pinia store (app.store.ts) which is them accessed in multiple components using a getter. Im creating stories for these components for my designer to view but the way i have coded the component accesses the store via a getter. I want to display all of the possible theme styles on the one page using storybook but I'm not too sure how to (if at all possible) update the store before i write the next story.

So `AuthInputTheme1` shoiuld use `theme_id` 1, and `AuthInputTheme2` should use `theme_id` 2. Is this possible or should i just pass in this id as a prop?

Code examples are below:

storybook/preview.ts

```
const pinia = createPinia();

setup((app: App): void => {
  app.use(FloatingVue)
  app.use(pinia);
});

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

stortbook file

```
import AuthInput from './AuthInput.vue';

const meta = {
  title: 'Molecule/AuthInput',
  component: AuthInput,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  args: {},
} satisfies Meta<typeof AuthInput>;

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const AuthInputTheme1: Story = {
  args: {},
};

#update store here?

export const AuthInputTheme2: Story = {
  args: {},
};
```

app.store.ts

```
export const useAppStore = defineStore('appStore', {
    state: (): IntakeFormStore => ({
        theme_id: 1,
    })
};
```

Comment: Maybe there's a way to make a global component that allows you to mutate theme from within Storybook? If you _must_ have different stories per theme, I would look at overriding the theme at the component level with a prop, rather than trying to mutate the store. Curious to see what others say.

Comment: You can do this in story component

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think i might have gone about it wrong myself. There is a top level component for each theme which could pass down the theme id to each component which i only thought about doing when i hit this problem. Instead of rewriting the component i was curious if it was possible to do this. I have seen stories wrote in different ways but as I'm new to storybook I'm not too sure about them.

Comment: @EstusFlask, sorry how would you do this?

Comment: By using useAppStore() inside a component. This is the most simplistic way, provide custom component like component: AuthInputStory that wraps original AuthInput and add any custom testing logic there. Or you can add logic to Preview comp to accept custom args that add initial pinia state, something like this https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/decorators#context-for-mocking , make sure "vue" is checked at the top of the doc